# Android exception handling, program halts

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm trying to catch a login exception thrown by the class that readerAccount belongs to in the code below.

```
while(!readerAccount.isAuthenticated()) {
    try {
        readerAccount.login();
    } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
        cmDialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(this.mCtx, "login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Google Reader API","login failed");
        continue;
    }
}
```

However, the only part of the catch statement that happens is is the Log.w() function.  I was under the impression that during a catch statement, you have the opportunity to recover from errors, but the program blacks out the screen altogether and the dialog is not displayed, nor is the Toast.  What's going on here?

Comment: Is this code executing within the UI thread?

Comment: is it possible that your code in the catch statement is throwing another exception? (e.g. cmDialog is null, so cmDialog.show() would throw an exception). What do you see in logcat? exception msg, stack trace??

Comment: cmDialog is defined earlier.  otherwise you'd get a compile-time error... right?

i'm able to show the dialog outside the catch statement and display the Toast without a problem.  but it won't work inside the catch statement.  furthermore, the Log.w() call is working fine: i can see it in logcat.

the issue is that when the exception occurs the screen turns black, which is rather unexpected, so it seems like video output simply halts, but logging works just fine.  why is this?

Comment: What is the value of isAuthenticated() after the exception is thrown?  Is it possible that isAuthenticated() is then returning true meaning that continue simply causes the loop to exit?

Comment: Can you add more code or details to see the context of where this snippet is running?

Comment: i think i've got it somewhat figured.  there's an infinite loop here and the dialog is getting shown (and shown, and shown) because program execution does not halt for the dialog.  it simply continues after the dialog is shown.  this is not the behavior i was after.
how can i show a dialog, wait for the dialog to close, and then continue program execution?  i tried this bit of code:

    cmDialog.show();
    while(cmDialog.isShowing());

but that just makes an infinite loop.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the answer to this.  the code that should be run after the dialog is interacted with should always be placed in the onClickListener for the specific dialog being displayed.  so the login() function should be called from within the onClickListener and if an unsuccessful login occurs, the dialog should be recalled until a successful login is made.

thanks anyway everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the .login() call leads to changes of the other objects you use in the catch statement (specially when something goes wrong and that exception is thrown), or to the locking of resources related in some way with them, which might explain why the .show() and .makeTest(...) calls don't act the way you are expecting, inside the catch statement.

You might want to try printing attributes and information about the cmDialog object, before the try statement, and inside the catch statement, before the .show() call, to be able to compare and check if anything altered the object's state or the state of any of it's used resources.

I hope that helps.